# Filter in X axis, within a chart

Tags: excel, excel-2010, excel-2007

I want to use filter in X axis, within a chart in Excel, so that only the data for one value will be displayed at a time upon selection.

Kindly suggest me how to do this without using PivotChart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - Use a range to plot chart ... 
2 - I have selected XY scatter chart...
3 - Apply filter on cells for headers of X and Y 
4 - Filter the X values you want to select and your chart will show only the data which is visible from your filter results
Please see the attachment images for example..
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can I Display the filter inside the chart.?